# SUM and get AVG from two tables in MySQL with WHERE clause based on their DATE

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate-functions

Here is my code. I have a difficulty with it.

```
SELECT NAMA_GRUP, SUM(TOTAL_KPI_PROGRAM)/COUNT(ctr.TANGGAL) AS AVG_KPI, COUNT(ctr.TANGGAL) AS JUMLAH_TANGGAL, ctr.TANGGAL AS TANGGAL
FROM ckm_t_grup ctg, ckm_t_program ctp, ckm_t_rundown ctr, ckm_t_calculate ctc
WHERE ctg.ID_GRUP = ctp.ID_GRUP AND ctp.ID_PROGRAM = ctr.ID_PROGRAM AND ctr.ID_RUNDOWN = ctc.ID_RUNDOWN AND (ctr.TANGGAL BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-15')
GROUP BY ctr.TANGGAL, NAMA_GRUP

UNION

SELECT NAMA_GRUP, SUM(TOTAL_KPI_PROGRAM)/COUNT(ctr.TANGGAL) AS AVG_KPI, COUNT(ctr.TANGGAL) AS JUMLAH_TANGGAL, ctr.TANGGAL AS TANGGAL
FROM ckm_t_grup ctg, ckm_t_program ctp, ckm_t_rundown ctr, ckm_t_calculate_2 ctcc
WHERE ctg.ID_GRUP = ctp.ID_GRUP AND ctp.ID_PROGRAM = ctr.ID_PROGRAM AND ctr.ID_RUNDOWN = ctcc.ID_RUNDOWN AND (ctr.TANGGAL BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-15')
GROUP BY ctr.TANGGAL, NAMA_GRUP
```

All I want is just to SUM the column 'AVG_KPI', JUMLAH_TANGGAL and do the AVG of 'AVG_KPI' with total from JUMLAH_TANGGAL. Well, here is the result from my query above.

Here's my picture of my query result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ4ma.png

Is there someone can give me some advice? I really stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
SELECT NAMA_GRUP, SUM(TOTAL_KPI_PROGRAM)/COUNT(TANGGAL) AS AVG_KPI, COUNT(TANGGAL) AS JUMLAH_TANGGAL
(
    SELECT NAMA_GRUP, TOTAL_KPI_PROGRAM, ctr.TANGGAL
    FROM ckm_t_grup ctg, ckm_t_program ctp, ckm_t_rundown ctr, ckm_t_calculate ctc
    WHERE ctg.ID_GRUP = ctp.ID_GRUP AND ctp.ID_PROGRAM = ctr.ID_PROGRAM AND ctr.ID_RUNDOWN = ctc.ID_RUNDOWN AND (ctr.TANGGAL BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-15')
    UNION
    SELECT NAMA_GRUP, TOTAL_KPI_PROGRAM, ctr.TANGGAL
    FROM ckm_t_grup ctg, ckm_t_program ctp, ckm_t_rundown ctr, ckm_t_calculate_2 ctcc
    WHERE ctg.ID_GRUP = ctp.ID_GRUP AND ctp.ID_PROGRAM = ctr.ID_PROGRAM AND ctr.ID_RUNDOWN = ctcc.ID_RUNDOWN AND (ctr.TANGGAL BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-15')
) as tmp
GROUP BY NAMA_GRUP, TANGGAL
```

This will resolve your issue